# Корень слова ОНИ

Tags: грамматика

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой корень в слове  **они**.

Answer (score 4):

И.п. Он, он/а, он/о, он/и, корень "он".

Answer (score 3):

В древнерусском языке ОН --- указательное местоимение:

ОН-Ъ (мужск.р.), ОН-А (женск.р., ОН-О (ср.р.).

И.п. ОН-ъ

Р.п. ОН-ого

Д.п. ОН-ому  и т.д.

Впоследствии формы Им.п. местоимения ОНЪ, ОНА, ОНО объединились с формами косвенных падежей другого указательного местоимения И, Я, Е:

Р.п. ЕГО

Д,п. ЕМУ и т.д.

Современная парадигма, таким образом, выглядит так:

И.п. ОН

Р.п. ЕГО

Д.п. ЕМУ и т.д.,

и поэтому по падежным формам вычленить окончание  и КОРЕНЬ в местоимении ОН невозможно. И в этом случае необходимо ориентироваться только на родовые и числовые формы этого местоимения: ОН-0, ОН-а, ОН-о, ОН-и. Отбросив изменяемую морфему --- окончание, получим корень ОН-.

Answer (score 2):

На мой вкус современные местоимения (равно как и первообразные предлоги, некоторые междометия, частицы и т.п.) лучше всего вообще не разлагать на морфемы. Больно уж путаный вопрос - и требует определенных знаний по исторической грамматике и древнерусского языка вообще.

Но в историческом плане... "ОН", конечно, корень. А вот что такое "И"???
Сравните, парадигмы склонения "ОН" и "И" (по [[@Антонова](/users/578/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0)](/users/578/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0)) весьма любопытны. Второе указательное местоимение как-то очень подозрительно напоминает падежные окончания при склонении местоимения ОН (для всех трех родов). Дело в том, что в древнерусском языке функции личных местоимений вообще были ограничены по сравнению с современным состоянием (личных местоимений третьего лица вообще не существовало, ОН тоже восходит к указательным местоимениям), а вот указательные местоимения были весьма продуктивны во всех смыслах. 
Упомянутые указательные местоимения И (Я, Е - и во множественном предположительно - ИИ) помимо прочего исполняли функцию своеобразного определенного артикля (послелога), "крепившегося" к концу слова. Остатки такого прикрепления можно наблюдать у современных полных прилагательных. Прикрепились они и к другому местоимению, "ОН-" как раз - ради образования личных родовых и числовых форм.

Так вот, будет по крайней мере непротиворечиво полагать, что И, А, О в *Они, Она, Оно* остатки древнего местоимения-послелога и, таким образом, тоже своего рода корень.

Другое дело, что детям в школе лучше этим вовсе не заморачиваться, дабы учителку до обморока не довести. И считать ОН корнем, а И - флексией. В современном языке это вполне справедливо.

Впрочем, моей первой мысли, что такие местоимения еще бы лучше вообще не членить на морфы, это не отменяет.

Answer (score 1):

Надо бы дополнить.

современные местоимения 
**его** обязано местоимению **он**  через  форму **оный**,   разговорные евоный,ево --> его. 
а форма оный  в значениях этот, тот самый, вышеозначенный стала использоваться в 18 веке и в 20 уже устарела. 
**ему** обязано  форме   **оне** (в значении-другой, другие) через переход оному, он**ему**-->ему, им, они.  старые формы   сим, сему, сей

**ей**  обязана старой форме сей, Сiя

все эти старые формы восходят к местоимению   се(це в украинском)  в значении  это, это есть. с переходом в западно европейских языках типа английского в  it is, в латыни id est и не в коем случае не наоборот.

Comment: Это ваше собственное мнение или ссылка имеется?

Comment: >ей обязана старой форме сей, Сiя  
  
Наоборот.

Comment: собственное.  можно и самому без помощников подумать...да и грамматик до Ломоносова не сыскать.
я ему сказал   Рекао сам му     здесь одно местоимение  му
оному сказал  оному рекао       а тут два в одном
                 сербский язык, вроде просто  из му к оному, а вот не наоборот ли в сторону упрощения, в сербском это просматривается.
це- тут двух мнений быть не может--указательное местоимение одно из первых, ближе к возгласу.
что до наоборот, думаю нет, скорее опять конкатенация в сторону упрощения.
тут надо анализировать и другие славянские грамматики.