# Него — его, нему — ему, ним — им

Tags: этимология, местоимения, историческая-грамматика

Относится ли «н» в таких словах, как *него, нему, ним, них, ними*, к этимологическому корню, или это просто нечто вроде прослойки между предлогом и последующим словом, наподобие *внити, принять, внутрь, внушить, снискать*?

Примечание: не так давно вроде даже говорили *у **е**й*.

Comment: Пока ждёте ответа: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/40426/%d0%9a%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%9e%d0%9d%d0%98

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Исторически *н* — это частичка предлогов, которые выглядели как **сън, *вън, *кън*.

Звук *н* в указанных вами местоимениях *него, ним* и т. д. называется эвфонической вставкой и сохранился, в общем, потому, что эти местоименные формы косвенных падежей. То есть, например, восстанавливается исходное сочетание **vъn-(j)ego*, перешедшее затем в *вън-его*, а в конце концов и в *в него*. Морфемные границы в слове изменились, и *н* стал считаться частью корня местоимения, а не предлога.

Действительно, слова *внутрь*, ст.-слав. *вънити* исторически тоже возникли из сложения предлога с сущ.: *vъn и *ǫtrь; *vъn-jьti соотв.

Comment: Согласна, если предлоги  присоединялись к словам, начинающимся с согласного звука,  н отпадало по закону открытых слогов. Если же следующее слово начиналось с гласного, то н сохранялось и отходило к следующему слову. Например, сън тобои > съ тобои, кън ему > къ нему, вън емь > въ немь и т.д. Впоследствии звук н стали прибавлять к местоимениям после любого предлога, например: оу него, за нимь и т.д.

Comment: @Людмила всё бы хорошо, да [j] — звук согласный, и с него начинаются местоимения его и проч.

Comment: Не совсем так, речь идёт о фонетическом слоге, а тогда  е  обозначает мягкость предшествующего согласного, а не два звука.

Comment: @Людмила 1. vъ(n???) ognь -- _н_ исчез. «Если же следующее слово начиналось с гласного, то н сохранялось и отходило к следующему слову» не работает.  2. «Если предлоги присоединялись к словам, начинающимся с согласного звука, н отпадало по закону открытых слогов»: прокомментируйте, основываясь на вашем правиле, пожалуйста, следующие примеры: vъn + **j**egda = в**н**егда, vъ(n???)+jahati = **vj**ahati. Как-то не работает оно. И йот, который, по-вашему, должен давать лишь мягкость предшествующему звуку, кое-где вполне себе сохраняется.

Comment: По-моему, мы начинали с местоимений (там действует закон открытого слога и переразложение), а перешли к ассимиляции и вопросу об исконном и протетическом  [j] . Перед формами указательного местоимения *jь, *jе, *jа, где произошло переразложение: конечный *n отошел к последующей словоформе и смягчился под влиянием начального *j формы местоимения: *vъn jemь > vъ njemь> vъ n’jemь > vъ n’emь, *sъn jьmi > sъ njьmi > sъ n’jьmi > sъ n’imi, *kъn jemu > kъ njemu > kъ n’jemu > kъ n’emu.

Comment: Ассимиляция согласных перед *j начала осуществляться задолго до утраты закрытых слогов ,  в этот период предлоги *vъn, *sъn, *kъn с формами указательного местоимения *jь, *jе, *jа, в силу краткости последних, составляли достаточно тесное фонетическое единство, что способствовало перемещению слоговой границы с последующим смягчением *n под влиянием *j и включением n’ в состав корня: *vъn jь > vъ njь > vъ n’ь, *vъn je > vъ nje > vъ n’e, *sъn jьmь > sъ njьmь > sъ n’imь и т.п.

Comment: @Людмила важно то, что вы сказали «если предлоги присоединялись к словам...»: к словам, а не только местоимениям.