# Ось и основание

Tags: этимология

Можно ли отнести слова "ось" и "основа" к этимологически однокоренным?

Допуская то, что буква «н» во втором из них является [эвфонической вставкой](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448258/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%BC).

Учитывая наличие следующего словообразовательного примера:

лик -> ликование;
пир -> пирование;
обет -> обетование

Answer (score 0):

Существительное *основа* произошло от глагола *сновать* «подготовлять основу для тканья, перематывая необходимое количество нитей с катушек на общий большой вал». Восходит к корню * *(s)n-* (такой он у Уоткинса, у Старостина * *snēy-*, у Коблера и Покорного * *(s)nē-*). Отсюда можно сделать вывод, что *н* никакая не «вставка». *Ось* восходит к * *h₂eḱs-* «острый». Пересечений не вижу.

Comment: Понимаю концепт вашего ответа, но, честно говоря, не понимаю, что доказывает простоe упоминание реконструкций пракорня. Другое дело, показать, как _ось_ оказалась того же корня, что и какой-то там пра-и.-е. корень...

Comment: Упоминание этих морфов, во-первых, доказывает, что *н* не вставка, а неотъемлемая часть корня, в отличие от *с*, а во-вторых, показывает, что сходство слов *ось* и *основа* случайное. *Ось* < * *aḱs-* (тут, видимо, переход * *ḱ* в *s*, см. «кентум-сатем») < * *h₂eḱs-* (по ларингальной теории * *h₂e* переходит в *a*).

Comment: Еще не хватает объяснения перехода и.-е. _*a_ > праслав. _*o_  (с обоснованием, почему не образовалась гемината, появился ь на конце; + описание фонетических и морфологических процессов протославянского периода)... А так-то оно так, только почему бы вам не добавить это в ответ? Ведь от этого он станет более понятным, не правда ли? ;)